# Array key index comes with number

Tags: php, variables, foreach, syntax, syntax-error

I am working on an array that is in the form below:

```
[
    {
        "id": "bitcoin",
        "name": "Bitcoin",
        "symbol": "BTC",
        "rank": "1",
        "price_usd": "7598.02",
        "price_btc": "1.0",
        "24h_volume_usd": "5106040000.0",
        "market_cap_usd": "128754238591",
        "available_supply": "16945762.0",
        "total_supply": "16945762.0",
        "max_supply": "21000000.0",
        "percent_change_1h": "0.01",
        "percent_change_24h": "-5.69",
        "percent_change_7d": "-14.2",
        "last_updated": "1522317867",
        "price_eur": "6162.0702002",
        "24h_volume_eur": "4141049500.4",
        "market_cap_eur": "104420975040"
    },
    {
        "id": "ethereum",
        "name": "Ethereum",
        "symbol": "ETH",
        "rank": "2",
        "price_usd": "415.793",
        "price_btc": "0.0552943",
        "24h_volume_usd": "1521500000.0",
        "market_cap_usd": "40949398071.0",
        "available_supply": "98485059.0",
        "total_supply": "98485059.0",
        "max_supply": null,
        "percent_change_1h": "-1.02",
        "percent_change_24h": "-9.97",
        "percent_change_7d": "-24.69",
        "last_updated": "1522317854",
        "price_eur": "337.21228093",
        "24h_volume_eur": "1233951715.0",
        "market_cap_eur": "33210371330.0"
    }
]
```

Now I want to get this array in PHP in FOREACH LOOP, but it throws an syntax error when I am put this code

```
**<?php echo $price_usd = $myVariable->24h_volume_usd ?>**
```

because any variable doesn't start with the number. How Can I get the **24h_volume_usd** values with the help of FOREACH LOOP.
Help me in this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried with array index . i.e : `$myVariable['24h_volume_usd']`

Comment: @B.Desai, Yes I did, but it throw an error 
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: post your full code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this:

```
$data = json_decode($dataStr, true); //When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays. 
foreach($data as $val){
    echo "\n".$val['24h_volume_eur'];
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/26PNC)

Comment: @Boyka, you can take help from this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Comment: I did, will you like the ques. too for me ? :)